# Reading file into CLIPS command line

Tags: file, clips

```
(defrule display_Pap_en_Vleis
    (answerc1 ?answPV)
    (test (integerp ?answPV))
    (test (= ?answPV 1))
  =>
    (open "C:\Users\Jennifer\Desktop\Results.dat" data "r")
    (read "C:\Users\Jennifer\Desktop\Results.dat")
    (close data)
)
```

Above we have the following CLIPS code.  Everything works up until the file queries.  When we run the clips program we receive the following:

```
[ROUTER1] Logical name C:UsersJenniferDesktopResults.dat was not recognized by any routers
[PRCCODE4] Execution halted during the actions of defrule display_Pap_en_Vleis.
```

We are trying to display a recipe on the CLIPS command line.  Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

```
(defrule display_Pap_en_Vleis
    (answerc1 ?answPV)
    (test (integerp ?answPV))
    (test (= ?answPV 1))
  =>
    (open "C:\\Users\\Jennifer\\Desktop\\Results.dat" data "r")
    (bind ?data (readline data))
    (while (neq ?data EOF)
       (printout t ?data crlf)
       (bind ?data (readline data)))
    (close data)
)
```